# UISwipeGestureRecognizer Direction (left/Right) with 4 subView

Tags: ios, xcode, gesture-recognition

i use this code to slide between two views with UISwipeGestureRecognizer Direction (left/Right)

and i want to do the same with 4 views :

view1->view2->view3->view4

view1<-view2<-view3<-view4

thank you for help

```
    //........towards right Gesture recogniser for swiping.....//
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[cmmtView addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
[rightRecognizer release];

//........towards left Gesture recogniser for swiping.....//
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(leftSwipeHandle:)];
leftRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[leftRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[cmmtView addGestureRecognizer:leftRecognizer];
[leftRecognizer release];
```

and

```
- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
    // load a different viewController
    [cmmtView addSubview:viewCmd2];
} else {
    // load an even different viewController        
    [viewCmd removeFromSuperview];
    [viewCmd2 removeFromSuperview];
    [viewFocus removeFromSuperview];
    [viewWeb removeFromSuperview];
    [viewLive removeFromSuperview];
    [viewLivePatch removeFromSuperview];
    [viewLivePatchConsole removeFromSuperview];}}

- (void)rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
    // load a different viewController       
    [viewCmd2 addSubview:cmmtView];
} else {
    // load an even different viewController
    [viewCmd removeFromSuperview];
    [viewCmd2 removeFromSuperview];
    [viewFocus removeFromSuperview];
    [viewWeb removeFromSuperview];
    [viewLive removeFromSuperview];
    [viewLivePatch removeFromSuperview];
    [viewLivePatchConsole removeFromSuperview];}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using

```
if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {    }
```

If the gesture recognizer direction is already set to left, it will always be left.  Your else statements will never run.

If you want to control views the way you mentioned, I suggest you declare a viewArray and currentIndex property and then handle it like so.

## In Your .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray * viewArray;
@property int currentViewIndex;
```

## In your .m

```
UIView * view1; // == yourView;
UIView * view2; // == yourView;
UIView * view3; // == yourView;
UIView * view4; // == yourView;
self.currentViewIndex = 0;
self.viewArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, view4, nil];
```

Then, in your handlers, retrieve the views this way.

```
- (void)leftSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
        if ((self.currentViewIndex + 1) < self.viewArray.count) {
            UIView * viewCurrentlyShowing = self.viewArray[self.currentViewIndex];
            UIView * viewToShow = self.viewArray[self.currentViewIndex + 1];

            // do whatever with views

            self.currentViewIndex = self.currentViewIndex + 1;
        }
        else {
            // Reached end of views 
        }
}

}

- (void) rightSwipeHandle:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if ((self.currentViewIndex - 1) >= 0) {
        UIView * viewCurrentlyShowing = self.viewArray[self.currentViewIndex];
        UIView * viewToShow = self.viewArray[self.currentViewIndex - 1];

        // do whatever with views

        self.currentViewIndex = self.currentViewIndex - 1;
    }
    else {
        // reached front of views
    }
```

Comment: little problem....

After 4 left swipe a have 

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'

i don't understand why this line not work's...

    if (self.currentViewIndex >= self.viewArray.count) self.currentViewIndex = self.viewArray.count - 1;

Comment: Updated to catch index range before getting viewToShow property. Let me know if this is working for you.